# How to compile typescript modules with baseUrl/paths settings in tsconfig

Tags: typescript

I develop components library distributed via npm and actively use `baseUrl` setting in tsconfig. It is really great, so I can easily write

```
// <prjRoot>/src/some/deeply/nested/module
import { Component } from 'components';
```

instead of horrible

```
// <prjRoot>/src/some/deeply/nested/module
import { Component } from '../../../src/components';
```

Also, I distribute not compiled bundle, but pure separate es6 modules. I have main `index.ts` file with reexports like this

```
export * from './src/components';
export * from './src/another-dir-components';
```

And here comes the time to build package and publish it to npm - TS doesn't replace paths to relative. Users get an error like "Cannot find module 'components'", because their TypeScript (or they may not use TS at all) or Webpack doesn't know anything about my baseUrl setting.

There is a solution via babel - [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver)

It works, but only for code. If I have such code

```
import { Component } from 'components'; // actually <prjRoot>/src/components/index.ts
import { SomeInterface } from 'typings'; // <prjRoot>/src/typings/index.ts
...
export default Klass extends React.Component {}
```

I will get

**file.js**. TS kicked off all about types (e.g. `import { SomeInterface }`), then Babel transpiles code and replace `from 'components'` on `from '../../../components'`. Great:

```
import { Component } from '../../../components';
...
/*#__PURE__*/
var Klass = (function (React.Component) {...transpiled babel code...})(React.Component);
export { Klass as default }
```

**file.d.ts** (still NOT relative path, will be error):

```
import { SomeInterface } from 'typings';
...
```

Comment: I guess you already solved this issue by using this: https://gist.github.com/rifler/39fdcd92e78505bbc94dc5b9f845292b Maybe you can share it as an answer.